# Is there a NATIVE jQuery method to pull an individual QueryString item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, jscript

Given an Url like this: `http://mydomain.com/mypage.asp?Animal=Elephant`

VBScript provides a nice way to get individual items in a QueryString using the Request object:

```
dim animal = Request.QueryString["Animal"]
```

I've seen some rather convoluted JavaScript floating around to do something similar, but I would hope that the jQuery library would have a function to do this without having to reinvent some wheel.  I can't find it in the jQuery book I have, nor on the jQuery website.

Am I barking up the tree at nothing?  Is there a NATIVE jQuery function to do this?

Please note that my question is asking for the existence of a ***NATIVE JQUERY FUNCTION*** to get a QueryString which is comparable to the VBScript I provided above.  A ONE LINE SOLUTION to the question.  Such as:

```
var animal = $.getParameterByName("Animal");
```

There are only 2 possible answers to my question.  They are:

1. No, there isn't a native one-line jQuery function as described, or
2. Yes, there is a native one-line jQuery function as described, and here it is...

I know how to get the entire QueryString and how to parse it using Javascript - what I don't know is if there is a jQuery method or function that does what I ask.

Comment: without a plugin, no there isn't. But it isn't too difficult to make on your own, just take the window.location and split it on `?`, then again on `&`, and then finally on `=`

Comment: use javascript => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values

Comment: Sigh.  Yes, @KevinB I know how to do it using Javascript already.  I want to know if there is a one-liner in the jQuery library that does it.  See my revised question.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea see my revised question.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist my original comment answers that: "*without a plugin, no there isn't.*"

Comment: I saw that @KevinB, and thankyou, but I was responding that I already know how to pull the window.location and parse a string using splits in Javascript.  If your answer is "No there isn't" then why don't you provide an Answer that says so instead of a comment?  Just sayin'.  I was just hoping that despite all evidence to the contrary that there was a native jQuery function as described.  I am surpised actually that there isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"No, there isn't a native one-line jQuery function as described"*

However, it's very easy to change that.

```
(function($){
    function getParameterByName(name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
            results = regex.exec(location.search);
        return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    $.getParameterByName = getParameterByName;
})(jQuery);
```

with that included in the head after jquery, you can now simply do:

```
var animal = $.getParameterByName("Animal");
```

Method for getting parameter by name taken from: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values#answer-901144)

Comment: That's what I needed!  "No there isn't, but here's how to remedy it."  I was already aware of that particular routine (got it from the same place, in fact), but thanks bunches for packaging it in a "jQuery-like" form.  Just what the Dr. ordered.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't answer you question, but I agree that the VBScript way does feel nice.

```
window.Request = {
  QueryString: {}
};

window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&').forEach(function(kv){
  Request.QueryString[kv.split('=')[0]] = decodeURIComponent(
    kv.split('=')[1].replace(/\+/g, " ")
  );
});

var animal = Request.QueryString['animal'];
```